# Firebase cloud function running into infinite loop

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am trying to make a cloud function which listens to the images being uploaded to the firebase storage bucket and triggers the function to resize the images. I am just taking the original image and writing it with the same name, thus updating the same image. Here is my code,

```
let functions = require('firebase-functions');

let admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();


const mkdirp = require('mkdirp-promise');

const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();

const spawn = require('child-process-promise').spawn;
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');


const THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT = 1000;
const THUMB_MAX_WIDTH = 1000;

const THUMB_PREFIX = '';


exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {
// File and directory paths.
const filePath = object.name;
const contentType = object.contentType; // This is the image MIME type
const fileDir = path.dirname(filePath);
const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
const thumbFilePath = path.normalize(path.join(fileDir, `${fileName}`));
const tempLocalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath);
const tempLocalDir = path.dirname(tempLocalFile);
const tempLocalThumbFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), thumbFilePath);

// Exit if this is triggered on a file that is not an image.
if (!contentType.startsWith('image/')) {
console.log('This is not an image.');
return null;
}

// Exit if the image is already a thumbnail.


// Cloud Storage files.
const bucket = gcs.bucket(object.bucket);
const file = bucket.file(filePath);
const thumbFile = bucket.file(thumbFilePath);
const metadata = {
contentType: contentType,
// To enable Client-side caching you can set the Cache-Control headers here. Uncomment below.
// 'Cache-Control': 'public,max-age=3600',
};

// Create the temp directory where the storage file will be downloaded.

return mkdirp(tempLocalDir).then(() => {
// Download file from bucket.
return file.download({destination: tempLocalFile});
}).then(() => {
console.log('The file has been downloaded to', tempLocalFile);
// Generate a thumbnail using ImageMagick.
return spawn('convert', [tempLocalFile, '-thumbnail', 
`${THUMB_MAX_WIDTH}x${THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT}>`, tempLocalThumbFile], {capture: 
['stdout', 'stderr']});
}).then(() => {
console.log('Thumbnail created at', tempLocalThumbFile);
// Uploading the Thumbnail.
return bucket.upload(tempLocalThumbFile, {destination: thumbFilePath, 
metadata: metadata});
}).then(() => {
console.log('Thumbnail uploaded to Storage at', thumbFilePath);
// Once the image has been uploaded delete the local files to free up disk space.
fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile);
fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalThumbFile);
// Get the Signed URLs for the thumbnail and original image.

const config = {
  action: 'read',
  expires: '03-01-2500',
};

return Promise.all([
  thumbFile.getSignedUrl(config),
  file.getSignedUrl(config),
]);

}).then((results) => {
console.log('Got Signed URLs.');
const thumbResult = results[0];
const originalResult = results[1];
const thumbFileUrl = thumbResult[0];
const fileUrl = originalResult[0];

// Add the URLs to the Database

return admin.database().ref('images').push({path: fileUrl, thumbnail: 
thumbFileUrl});
}).then(() => console.log('Thumbnail URLs saved to database.'));
});
```

I function keeps executing and ultimately stops with quota exceeded message. I think the idea of writing over the same name is causing the problem. But its all what I want. Is there a way to stop this loop?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write some code in your function that checks to see if the file you're uploading back to your bucket should not be further processed, exiting early.  This is exactly what is happening in the [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/convert-images) that you may have copied to get where you are now.  Except you'll need a different way to determine if the function to stop early.  Maybe look at the name or path of the file.